# removing a circuit from a circuit breaker

Tags: electrical-panel

I have one circuit breaker connected to three different items, a garage door opener, a water conditioner, and an alarm system. As I am not using the alarm system I want to remove it from the circuit breaker. How is this done/

Comment: What do you mean "remove it"? Is the alarm plugged into an outlet or hard-wired? Chances are they're all connected to one home run, and you'd have to trace the circuit and find where it branches.

Comment: There is probably a junction downstream from your panel.  You may be able to hard wire three circuits directly to one breaker, but it certainly wouldn't be smart.  Do you happen to know the electrical draw on that water conditioning system?  I would think that should be on a dedicated breaker.

Comment: @mreff555 Most water softeners/filters have some electronics or a timer in the filter head that draws a few milliwatts, and a motor that draws a few hundred milliwatts once a day or so when it turns the valve to run the backwash cycle. Most plug in with a 12 or 24VDC adapter. No need for dedicated circuit.

Comment: My mistake. I assumed they would use a larger pump.

Answer (score -1):

Just turn it off and tape it so it stays off. Off does translate to completely dead and not even some stand-by power can be obtained. You never want to remove any wiring completely, regardless of your use or non-use...you don't know the future nor the future occupants. If you need the circuit for another new circuit, then your Electrician (not you) would just disconnect the old circuit from the breaker and run the new circuit.